# Loop Stops any error occurs in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package where it pulls all table data from one server and insert into another database which is another server. I am using ADO.NET Connection for both source and Target connection.

Using SQLBulkCopy I am looping thru each table data from source and pushing into target. Same time after pushing data into target I am logging this information into a SQL table , SSIS_LOG .

If Sucess happens the logging into the table SSIS_LOG  happens correctly. But if Any Error happens it is not coming to the Execute SQL task  and the For loop stops . It doesn't continue further.

Please help me.

I am logging the error information into my SQL table.
For example, Primary key Constraint voilation , Table Not found etc.

Id  Date    PackageName TableName   RowsCount   IsSucess    Error
617 2018-07-11  Package crm.tblObjectType20036  0   1   Invalid object name tblObjInstPerm.

Now I am able to do this with Precedence Constraint. But If any error happens the for loop stops, It doesn't continue further,

What I want is Foo loop should iterate thru on each object and Log thru in the table whether it should success or failure.

Comment: Can you give an example of what should happen? In my opinion you should fail the package on error so you minimize the risk of bad data in the destination.

Comment: Why would you expect the loop to continue after an error?   What have you done to code it that way?  It's not the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a loop to continue after an error, then set the MaximumErrorCount to 0. You can do this by clicking on either the For or Foreach enumerator, which will populate the Properties window in the bottom right. In there, you will see the MaximumErrorCount property.